# How to determine if a Binary Tree node is a Left or Right child?

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a simple Tree data structure, however, I would like to implement two methods named `isLeftChild` and `isRightChild`.

The problem is I am having a very hard time understanding trees. The concept and general process has not fully been grasped.

Here is my simple tree so far:

```
class Node(object):
    ''' A tree node. '''
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def isLeftChild(self):
        ''' Returns True if the node is a left child, else False. '''
        pass

    def isRightChild(self):
        ''' Returns True if the node is a right child, else False. '''
        pass

    def insert(self, data):
        ''' Populate the tree. '''
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def printTree(self):
        ''' Display the tree. '''
        if self.left:
            self.left.printTree()
        print self.data
        if self.right:
            self.right.printTree()

def main():
    root = Node(8)
    root.insert(2)
    root.printTree()

main()
```

**How can I have a node determine if it is a left child or a right child** ***(without reference to its `data`)***?

I am not sure what I need to add to my tree in order to determine this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parent attribute and test if the memory reference if the parent's right or left is the same as the child's reference in memory. You're going to need a parent attribute to traverse the tree anyway.

```
return self is self.parent.left # in the isLeftChild
```